# Adjusting legend size in tmap

Tags: r, r-raster, tmap

I would like to control the legend size of a continuous legend in `tmap`. E.g. such that it is at the bottom and spanning the whole plot.

I tried all the `legend.outer.size` etc. options which did not work

Best workaround with minimal code so far is:

```
library(tmap)
library(raster)

tm_shape(land, projection = "robin", is.master = T) + 
     tm_raster("elevation", legend.is.portrait = F, style="cont", midpoint = NA, 
     palette = terrain.colors(50)) + tm_layout(earth.boundary = T,legend.outside = T, 
     legend.outside.position = "bottom", frame=F)

plot(land[["elevation"]], add=T, legend.only = T, horizontal = T, legend.shrink=0.66, 
     smallplot=c(0.1,0.9, 0.1, 0.15), col=terrain.colors(50))
```

[image: Resulting map]

Of course now there is a double legend and I could remove it from the `tmap`-Plot, but I want the `tmap` legend to look like the "plot" legend. I don't like my workaround because it totally breaks the nice tmap / ggplot approach.

Comment: See https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/312

Comment: Thanks - but what you write "When legend.outsize = TRUE [you mean: legend.outside I believe], legend.width will be set to .9, which basically means the whole page width.", does not seem to be true in my example. The legend only spans 1/3.

Comment: Indeed it should be legend.outside = TRUE. The actual width of the legend depends on the content of the legend itself. legend.width is just a upper bound. (See also second bullet point in the link above).

Comment: The repo moved. New URL to the link above: https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/issues/312